# When deploying a react site using netlify, it fails when a have an extra folder in my src folder but it works when I no longer have that folder

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy a react site project to netlify using github. It is the second project I have encontered this error.

In my first project I was able to deploy the site normally, but then I went back and a created a folder to store all my components related to a single component (E.g. all NavBar components to sit within a navBar folder). And for some reason netlify gave an error for it in the building stage. I was able to fix it by undoing the folder and just having all files in the src instead of src/folder/.

Here is my new project and the folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure:]

Imports in src/App.jsx:
[image]

Exports from src/Grocery/index.jsx:

[image]

Finally the errors I am getting from netlify when trying to deploy it:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone knows why this is happening. Or could let me know a solution for using folders in react applications and deploying it using netlify

Thank you very much!

P.S. There are no other errors or warnings being given by neither react or netlify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was commiting the files with `git commit -am <message>` but I forgot to do `git add *` after I created a new folder which made github to never have the folder with the files init.